# Book on electromagnetic with Tensors

Tags: book-recommendation, tensors

I've been reading the book "Introduction to Tensor Anlaysis and the Calculus of a Moving Surfaces" by Grinfeld.  He makes tantalizing claims in videos about this book, stating that tensors simplify the mathematics of vector analysis.

I very much like this idea, and would love an exposition of electromagnetics based on tensor analysis.   Could someone recommend such a book?

Comment: I found these notes helpful: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/category/mathematical-physics/electromagnetism/

Comment: I tried to read a book that talked about de Rham Hodge something something and cohomology in context of electromagnetism, perhaps google that. It was too complex for me at the time at least.

Comment: The book [Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach](http://matrixeditions.com/UnifiedApproach5thedSamples.html) by Hubbard and Hubbard contains a 14 page section on electromagnetism  (in chapter 6) that you'd probably like to read. Electromagnetism is presented (concisely) using the language of differential forms.